# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject: unwrap an object

Tags: c#, json.net

Given a JSON encoded string that can represent any valid JSON value or can wrap the expected value in an object like:

```
{"result": <value>}
```

How can I use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>` so that it returns the value hold by the property "result" if it exists ?

Basically, I would like to have

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyType>("{\"result\": <value>}")
    .Equals(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyType>("<value>"))
```

Comment: You're probably going to want a JsonConverter

Comment: Why can't you simply use `DeserializeObject<Wrapper>(json).Result` ? At some point code needs to determine that the wrapper is present, you could deserialize it into `JObject`, inspect the properties and keys and determine if you're dealing with a wrapper or not.

Comment: That's what I do for now. I was wondering if I could configure Json.net so that I can call DeserializeObject as is.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create a **`Wrapper`** class you can always use **`dynamic`** at your own risk:

```
(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString) as dynamic).result.ToObject<T>()
```